# Django TextField always empty submitted

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am following the django_rest_framework tutorial and I stuck part 4.
The problem is that whenever I am trying to post a new snippet by consuming
127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/ with curl or httpie everything works perfectly fine.

But whenever I want to do it by using the browsable API generated by the django_rest_framework

```
code = models.TextField()
```

I always get :

```
HTTP 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS

{
    "code": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

How is this possible ?

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import get_all_lexers, get_lexer_by_name
from pygments.styles import get_all_styles
from pygments.formatters.html import HtmlFormatter

LEXERS = [item for item in get_all_lexers() if item[1]]
LANGUAGE_CHOICES = sorted([(item[1][0], item[0]) for item in LEXERS])
STYLE_CHOICES = sorted((item, item) for item in get_all_styles())

class Snippet(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    code = models.TextField()
    linenos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='python', max_length=100)
    style = models.CharField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default='friendly', max_length=100)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='snippets')
    highlighted = models.TextField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Use the pygments library to create a highlighted HTML
        representation of the code snippet.
        """
        lexer = get_lexer_by_name(self.language)
        linenos = self.linenos and 'table' or False
        options = self.title and {'title': self.title} or {}
        formatter = HtmlFormatter(style=self.style, linenos=linenos, full=True, **options)
        self.highlighted = highlight(self.code, lexer, formatter)
        super(Snippet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
```

And here is my serializers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers
from snippets.models import Snippet, LANGUAGE_CHOICES, STYLE_CHOICES

class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style')

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    snippets = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Snippet.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'snippets')
```

From what I understand I can bypass it using :

```
key_word = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control','rows':1,'cols':10}))
```

but I would rather learn something and not fall for the hack-ish of doing it.

Comment: did you try making `code = models.TextField(blank=True)`?

Comment: Note that the position of the owner field in your SnippetSerializer is wrong, it shouldn't be in the Meta class.

Comment: @Hybrid Yes I did try it and with a `default='true'` too but the problem is even when I write something inside the field I still get an error such as `This field is required`

@Linovia Thank you for pointing me this, now it's a lot more logical, and fix one of the few problem I had. But the initial problem is still on.

Comment: I think I noticed something.
The same problem (I always get something empty) also apply with the title field bit this one accept to be blank so I never get the error.

I don't exactly understand everything but it seems that my save function does not get any value for code and title inside it.